# Saving the labels of scikit kmeans in an array with a row for each label

Tags: python, arrays, label, row, cluster-analysis

I'm doing a cluster analysis with kmeans from sklearn. Now I want to save the labels of kmeans in an array and I want each label in a separate row, but I only get them all in one row at the moment. 
This is my code:

k1 = KMeans(n_clusters = 3).fit(features)
pred = k1.predict(features)

results = np.array([k1.labels_])

results is the array in which I'm saving the labels of kmeans. But at the moment I only get one row with all the labels. But I want a row for each label. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
results=k1.labels_.reshape(k1.labels_.shape[0],1)
```

This will stack into 1 column multiple rows.